# when i want to get something from django rest api using react axios its show [object Object] in my console

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

when I try to get data from django rest framework its provide looks [objects objects]
for this reason i never map for actual data
here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
const getProduct = async () => {
  await Axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/peoduct/${id}`,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then((response) => {
      setPoduct(response?.data);
      console.log(response?.data +'ffa');
    })
   
  
 };

 getProduct();

},[id]);
```

Comment: did you check the `Network` tab in your browser? can you see the result here? is that API call successfully done with status 200?

Comment: what is the result of   `console.log(response.data)`
 ?

Comment: in console the result is [object Object]ffa   ProductDetail.jsx:28

Comment: I mean what are you trying to add 'ffa' with your data ?

Comment: there are many kinds of consoles in my project,  for the identification I call it ffa, its not the fact

Comment: I already wrapped it with a quotation

Comment: remove the `ffa` from your console and do this: console.log("myData:", response?.data)

Comment: You are trying to convert the `response.data` into string implicitly

Comment: its work, thank you

Comment: I'll post an answer with some explanation about your problem.

Comment: okay i will check

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is using **type coercion**. read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) documentation.

> Type coercion is the automatic or implicit conversion of values from one data type to another (such as strings to numbers). Type conversion is similar to type coercion because they both convert values from one data type to another with one key difference — type coercion is implicit whereas type conversion can be either implicit or explicit.

The issue is simple, let's explain it. assume, there is a number and string:

```
const myNumber = 1
const myString = "one"
```

Now, concatenate and log it:

```
const result = myNumber + myString
console.log(result) // "1one"
```

The `+` sign will convert the type of `myNumber` into `string` and then add **string** `1` with `one`

Now, repeat what about an **object**?

```
console.log({} + "one")  // [object Object]one
```

converting an object to a string will produce `[object Object]`.

If you want to track your console data, you can simply add a name without the `+` sign:

```
console.log("my reduer result is:" , myObject)
```

Comment: If your question is solved, please accept the solution. The ✔ is below the ▲/▼ arrow, at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. You may also vote on the usefulness of an answer with the ▲/▼ arrow. Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question. more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thank you @MdMostafijurRahman